# Boost regexp how to parse Cookie string into map<string, string>?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

So Cookie strings look like `remixsettings_bits=1; wysiwyg=1,2,3,abc; remixclosed_tabs=0; remixgroup_closed_tabs=786432; remixlang=0; remixchk=5; remixsid=35d4f9907281708019490d07728c27ca5c10e5de7a869c322222225e3219e; audio_vol=100`
 I wonder how to parse tham into map `name` <-> `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex: `(\w+)=([^;]*)`

1. `\w+` - alphanumeric one or more repetitions
2. `=`
3. `[^;]*` - any character except `;` any number of repetitions

Result:
[image]

Comment: this is only one side of the question. you do not say anething about how to use your regexp in boost.(

Comment: Because personally I do not get how to use it with boost regexp=(

Comment: @Kabumbus, Sorry, I don't know boost. I can't help you in this part of question. My apologies :-(